# Dead code with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, eclipse-plugin, drjava

I am getting a "Dead Code" warning on my battleship game. I am testing if a ship can be placed and am seeing different direction that the ship will face if it can be placed.

I then get input using [In.class](http://www.ecf.utoronto.ca/~jcarter/text/In.java) and after checking if it can be placed with a boolean (set to true/false when checking directions for placement) I use a 2D array of ints and set all of the locations to 1 (Starting location then + length (given as a parameter) in direction specified)

my .java file is here [ShipProperties.java](http://pastebin.com/iy2jwL9r)

if possible please keep answers to a beginners skill level (basic i/o and arrays, im pretty good with logic)

#### EDIT

I got it fixed and it now works as intended!

Just put the return in a if/else inside the loop

```
for(int i = length; i > 0; i--)
{
 grid[startLocX][startLocY + i] = 1;
 if(i == 0)
 {
   return grid;
 }
}
```

Comment: what should "dead code" be? Add some comments to your code otherwise no one will read this.

Comment: Post only the piece that gives you the warning.

Comment: As an aside, you have returns in your for loops.  That's not going to finish going through your arrays. Which could be filled using java.util.Arrays.fill().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,

```
    for(int i = length; i > 0; i--)                               //Dead Code
    {
      grid[startLocX - i][startLocY] = 1;
      return grid;
    }
```

decrement in loop is never executed because in first iteration of the loop your method return a value, so never do a second iteration. Actually your code is same as:

```
    if(length > 0)                              
    {
      grid[startLocX - length][startLocY] = 1;
      return grid;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So i assume I would decrement and set the array indexs to 1 then return the value?

Answer (score 1):

Your loops all return in the first iteration. E.g.

```
for(int i = length; i > 0; i--)
{
    grid[startLocX - i][startLocY] = 1;
    return grid;
}
```

does the same as

```
int i = length
if(i > 0)
{
    grid[startLocX - i][startLocY] = 1;
    return grid;
}
```

so your loop is unecessary. The actual dead code is `i--` which never gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move the return statement from inside the for loops to the end of the `if(canPlace == true)` clause. I'd also recommend you de-clutter the code a bit to make it more readable:

```
if(canPlace == true)
{
    for(int i = length; i > 0; i--)                            
    { // a little less efficient perhaps (will be optimized by JIT if it's critical), but a lot more readable for sure.
        switch (ans) {
        case "Left":
            grid[startLocX - i][startLocY] = 1;
            break;
        case "Down":
            grid[startLocX][startLocY - i] = 1;
            break;
        case "Right":
            grid[startLocX + i][startLocY] = 1;
            break;
        case "Up":
            grid[startLocX][startLocY + i] = 1;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("huh? " + ans);
        }
    }
}
// no need for an else clause since you return the grid anyway
return grid;
```

note that I'm using string switch-case (new in java 7) and check for unexpected argument.